# swift 3 popover with Xcode

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, segue, popover

i have an nstableview with custom cells.
each cell has a nsbutton.

now i would like to create an popover to another view controller, when the button was pressed.

**what i have done?**

i create a segue connection between my nstableview and the popover view controller and give it an identifier.

in my custom cell i created i IBOutle action for the nsbutton:

```
@IBAction func actionButtont(_ sender: Any) {

      let vcTable = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "vcTable ") as! TableView

      vcTable.startSegue(text: "Test")
}
```

and in my TableViewController:

```
var text = String()

func startSegue(text:String) {
   text = text
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Popover", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
   let vc = segue.destinationController as! Popover
   vc.text = text
}
```

My "text String" will passed successfully.
but me segue will not work, because my app crashes before with this error:

```
[General] -[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:]: view has no window. You must supply a view in a window.
```

what did I wrong?

Comment: nobody an idea?

Comment: *view has no window. You must supply a view in a window* is pretty meaningful, isn't it? Why do you `instantiate` the controller rather then designing the segue in IB? And it's highly recommended to use a *view based*  rather than a *cell based* table view.

Comment: why should i use a view based instead of a cell based table view? (for your information: i using a view based tableview). and how can i instantiate the designed segue instead of my controller?

Comment: A view based table view is state of the art and much more versatile (and much easier to handle) than the old-fashioned cell based table view. Like in iOS segues are designed and connected in Interface Builder. Anyway the initial controller in the storyboard must be a window controller (that's what the error message implies).

Comment: mmmh, my tableview controller is part of a window controller. in other words: how can i realize my situation? a tableview with custom view cells with a nsbutton. each button should open a popover. but i can't assign a popover directly to this nsbutton in storyboard. so i dont know how can i solve my problem :(